# Can I place iAd ADBannerView middle of the iPad app?

Tags: ios, ipad, iad

I could place iAd ADBannerView as a subview of a view , which sits at the middle of the screen.
So effectively the ad view will be at the middle of the ipad app.I did not change the size of the ADBannerView.
My questions are

1, will apple reject my app?

2, Can my ADBannerView receive ads from iAd network..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try it out.  After you open your app, you will see a test ad, if you click it it will tell you if it is working ok.

Otherwise, three is no rule that I know of about the placement of the ad,  you can place it wherever you like, the middle is fine.

Comment: I wants to place the ADBannerView  one scree only..will apple approve it?